# convert ('a - b') to ('a - c') using preg_replace function

Tags: php

I have got a question and I tried solve it, but I couldn't solve it because I'm unfamiliar with regular expressions, so what I want to do is is convert `'A - B'` to `'A - C'` using the [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) function.

For instance:

```
'Mon ~ Tue' => 'Mon ~ Wed'
```

How can I use `preg_replace` for this problem?

Comment: What exactly do you want to replace? An item with the one following it in some order? or the specific string 'Tue' with the specific string 'Wed'?

Comment: `$result = preg_replace('/Mon \~ Tue/g', 'Mon ~ Wed', $subject);` where `g` means "global" (replace all occurences). If a, b, c are variables, you'll have to do some escaping.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't require regular expressions.

```
str_replace('Mon ~ Tue', 'Tue', 'Wed');
```

Seems to work just fine.

Unless I'm missing something here?

Comment: If I understand correctly, `Mon ~ Tue` is actually a part of some larger string

Comment: Uh, I think you have put the parameters in the wrong order (it happens to me all the time with PHP).

Answer (score 1):

The code bellow seems to do the job, but it's hard to guess what exactly are you trying to do.

`$x = "Mon ~ Tue";
preg_replace("/(Mon ~ )Tue/", "\$1Wed", $x);`

Comment: No need to use a backreference

Comment: Guys, a simple string replacement does the job here, there is no need for regular expressions here.

Answer (score 1):

The basic replacement of a string with another you can do with `str_replace`, you need no regexp at all:

```
$string = str_replace('Tue', 'Wed', $string);
```

If you have a series of strings, for example,

```
$weekdays = array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun');
```

To replace every day with the following one, we could first generate the "rotated" array

```
$week_one = $weekdays;
$week_one[] = array_shift($week_one);
```

But due to the way `str_replace` works, **we cannot use str_replace($weekdays, $week_one, $string)** (it would replace Mon with Tue, then *that* Tue with Wed, then *that* Wed with Thu... and we'd end with all 'Mon'.

So we have to do it in two steps. In the first step we replace all strings with strings that surely aren't in the source set, nor in the target string. For example we replace Mon with {{{1}}}. In the second step we replace {{{1}}} with Tue.

```
$weekdays = array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun');
$replace  = array();
foreach($weekdays as $i => $day)
    $replace[] = '{{{'.$i.'}}}';

$string = str_replace($weekdays, $replace, $string);
// Then we rotate $replace in the opposite direction.
array_unshift($replace, array_pop($replace));
// And we reverse the replace.
$string = str_replace($replace, $weekdays, $string);
```

You can use a similar approach to replace only the second occurrence of a weekday in a string with the next weekday.